# gradle circular dependency with external project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a fairly simple setup, that does not work and I cannot work out why:

the folder structure is as follows:

```
/dependency
    /build.gradle
    /settings.gradle
    /src/main/...

/Mainproject
    /build.gradle
    /settings.gradle

    /Subproject_1
        /build.gradle
        /src/main...

     /Subproject_2
        /build.gradle
        /src/main...
```

I want the Subproject to depend on "dependency" locally for quick testing.
so I stuck to the manual and did:

**/Mainproject/settings.gradle:**

```
include "Subproject_1", "Subproject_2", "dependency"
project(":dependency").projectDir = file('../dependency')
```

**/Mainproject/build.gradle:**

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile project(path: ':dependency')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':Subproject_1')
    compile project(':Subproject_2')
}
```

**/dependency/build.gradle:**

```
version '1.0'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://...."
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Archive delegation dispatcher classes',
                'Implementation-Version': project.version
    }
}
```

The build.gradle files of Subproject_1 and _2 are empty.
The settings.gradle file of dependency is empty.

When i gradle build MainProject i get:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:dependency:classes
\--- :dependency:compileJava
     \--- :dependency:jar
          \--- :dependency:classes (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

And I cannot get my head around why that would be.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `include "dependency"` in your Mainproject's settings.gradle file, you are making the "dependency" project a subproject of "Mainproject".

Then this block in your Mainproject's build.gradle file defines "dependency" as a compile dependency of all subprojects.

```
allProjects {
    dependencies {
        compile project(path: ':dependency')
    }
}
```

Since the "dependency" project is also a subproject, you have a circular dependency defined where the "dependency" project depends on itself.

Instead, try creating a settings.gradle file for each of the subprojects with the following:

```
include "dependency"
project(":dependency").projectDir = file('../dependency')
```

Then modify your settings.gradle file for the Mainproject to look like this:

```
include "Subproject_1", "Subproject_2"
```

Comment: Realized it some 2 minutes after I posted, i went for all projects - project(':dependency'). Nontheless, thank you ^^

Answer (score 2):

You've stated that `allProjects` have a dependency on the project `dependency` as seen here:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile project(path: ':dependency')
    }
}
```

You need this to only apply to your projects that *aren't* `dependency`.  You can do that by excluding it when applying dependencies, like this

```
subprojects { project ->
    if (project.name != "dependency") {
        apply plugin: 'java'
        dependencies {
            compile project(path: ':dependency')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Because dependencies itself.
Move it must be OK.

Comment: I think this should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off `Instant run` worked for me, could work for someone else too. I had some changes related to `gradle` and my application appeared not to work after it.

Answer (score 0):

### build.gradle (:shared)

This is because you are trying to include a module inside of yourself.

From:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
    ...
}
```

To:

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

GL

[Source](https://github.com/google/iosched)